# mongodb db snapshots or inserting flags

Tags: mongodb

I have a massive insert operations (1000 docs per operation) and probably that it will fail during my code works.

Can I make some kind of snapshots or put some flags to database and if something goes wrong then revert db to flag/snapshot?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB intentionally [does not include support for ACID transactions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-support-transactions), however you can implement your own transactional semantics depending on your use case.

For batch inserts, a straightforward approach would be to:

- include a field with a unique batchID in the documents you are inserting
- use the MongoDB [bulk insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations/#bulk-inserts) method for efficiency
- on error, remove the documents in the failed batchID (assuming you want all-or-nothing for the inserts)

Answer (score 0):

there is no simple way to do that, like a simple flag. I think the best option to you is implement a two-phase commit approach, here you see detailed instruction to implement it: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Regards,
Moacy